# Nodejs app deployed to azure Webapp not working

Tags: node.js, azure, web-applications

I have deployed a Nodejs app (that is working on my local) to Azure Web app, however, I always a message in the browser as "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". Is there any way I can debug it and find the cause of the this message or is it because of the some common issue in case any one has faced this before ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several post around this issue. Here is something which you can try:

- When you deploy the zip file, open KUDU or application editor from Azuer web app, which you can find it here:

[image]

Sometime if it is under your custom folder , you might get this issue.

Additionally please refer the below link for further troubleshooting

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/512e2eca-a2f2-4b32-a934-1081bddcdc86/nodejsweb-apps-azure-quotyou-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-pagequot?forum=opensourcedevwithazure

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/issues/9

Also check this post for configuration:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps

Hope it helps.